# Is $f$ a probability mass function for a random variable $X$ if and only if it complies with these two properties?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification

I've read in multiple books that a function $F$ is a cumulative distribution function for some random variable $X$ if and only if it satisfies three conditions:

1. $F$ is non-decreasing.
2. $F$ is normalized.
3. $F$ is right-continuous.

but I've never seen an analogous set of conditions for a probability mass function; I think, however, that the conditions below would suffice. Am I correct?

**Theorem?:** A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ is a probability mass function for some discrete random variable $X$ (meaning $\text{im}(X)$ is countable) if and only if it satisfies the following two conditions:

1. $f(x)> 0$ for at most countably many $x$.
2. $\sum_{f(x)>0}f(x) = 1$.

$\def\BBB{\mathcal{B}}$ $\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$
*Proof:* It is clear that every pmf complies with both conditions. To show the converse, let both conditions hold for $f$, and define
$$P(B) = \sum_{0<f(x)\in B}f(x)$$
for any $B$ in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\BBB(\RR)$ of $\RR$, then $P$ is a probability measure on $(\RR,\BBB(\RR))$:

- If $B_1,B_2\ldots\in\BBB(\RR)$ are disjoint, then, letting $B=\bigcup B_k$, we have
  $$P(B) = \sum_{0<f(x)\in B}f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{0<f(x)\in B_k}f(x)\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(B_k).$$
- $P(\RR) = 1$.

Consider now the random variable $X=\text{id}$ from $(\RR,\BBB,P)$ to $(\RR,\BBB)$. Its pushforward measure $X_*P$ is given by $P$ itself, as
$$X_*P(B) = P(X^{-1}(B)) = P(B).$$
Finally, we note that $f$ is the pmf of $X$, as
$$P(X = x) = P(X^{-1}(x)) = P(x) = f(x).$$

Comment: Yes it's true. Generally speaking, what you are doing is defining a Radon-Nikodym derivative of the distribution of $X$ with respect to the counting measure on the discrete set on which your variate $X$ is supported on. So all you need is your $f$ to be non-negative in the discrete set and it should integrate (i.e. sum) to $1$.